# Check login and render web application in web view

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I'll keep this as simple as possible, the company I have recently joined has an established web application, they would like to build a mobile app to accomodate said web application.

Ideally they would like to create a very simple mobile app, so a standard login screen (username / password) and once authenticated they'd like to render the web application inside the app via a web view.  Reason for this, they don't want to invest to much time on this and they'd also like to start sending notifications.

Problem:

1. The web application does not make use of web api's, it's your standard MVC application with cookie based authentication.
2. When the end user provides a username and password I need to somehow check in the background if the credentials provided are valid - I can't use an API
3. If the credentials are valid and the user becomes authenticated I'm to then redirect them from the login screen to the dashboard where they'll continue to use the web application view a web view.

Question.

1. How can I check in the background without using an API the credentials provided are valid?
2. How can I check the response for any errors and pass them back to the login screen for the user to see / action?
3. If the credentials are good and the user becomes authenticated how can I redirect the user accordingly?

Can anyone else think of a better approach?

Comment: When login is done does the application load a new url?

Comment: It does yes, the web application has multiple different pages

Answer (score 0):

Listen changes with [onNavigationStateChange](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onnavigationstatechange) and based on `url` detect if a user is authenticated.

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: '...' }}
  onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
    const { url } = newNavState
    // TODO 
  }}
/>
```